# Add onclick event programmatically

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

How do I add an `onclick` event to a tag in HTML programmatically?

I want to be able to click a link, and have an `onclick` event attached to a Javascript function take effect on another tag.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
var element1 = document.createElement("input");
element1.type = "text";
element1.id="List["+num+"].id";
element1.name="List["+num+"].id";
element1.onclick="javascript:CalCal()";
cell1.appendChild(element1);
```

I want to call a Javascript function `CalCal()` on `onClick` event.  Is this possible?

Comment: tried using `jQuery`, your life will be much easier :D

Answer (score 34, accepted):

But keep in mind that `addEventListener` is supported in IE just from version 9. To support older versions of IE you could use something like that:

```
if (element1.addEventListener) {  // all browsers except IE before version 9
  element1.addEventListener("click", CalCal, false);
} else {
  if (element1.attachEvent) {   // IE before version 9
    element1.attachEvent("click", CalCal);
  }
}
```

Comment: i need to pass parameter also..how can i?

Comment: in this case you have to replace ```CalCal``` inside ```addEventListener``` and ```attachEvent``` with an anonymous function like this: ```function() { CalCal(yourParameter); }```

Answer (score 16):

**Yes you can add an onclick event programmatically in javascript like this:**

```
element1 = document.getElementById("your_tag_id");
element1.addEventListener("click", CalCal)
```

This attaches an onClick event to tags with id="your_tag_id".

You can also remove the onclick event like this:

```
element1.removeAttribute("click");
```

More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: what is proper way of adding events to an HTML elements, programtically using javascript or directly on HTML element? I guess  addEventListener() is often the better way to get notified of events, especially when wishing to apply various event handlers independently from each other on same element?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
element1.onclick=CalCal;
```

instead:

```
element1.onclick="javascript:CalCal()";
```

Comment: element1.onclick=function(){CalCal();} should be the correct syntax here.

Comment: Nope, `CalCal` is just an function reference, u would do also function reference creating anonymous `function(){}`.