# Use Js to change a buttons onclick value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button

```
<button id="buttonOne" onclick="pressOne()">Press</button>
```

i was wondering if it was possible using javascript to change the

```
onclick="pressOne()"
```

to

```
onclick="pressTwo()"
```

so the button would be

```
<button id="buttonOne" onclick="pressTwo()">Press</button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to contain the condition which determines which logic to run within a single function. What governs which function should be executed on click?

Comment: hmmm yeah its possible.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13229208/javascript-add-onclick-event-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it using this:

```
$("#buttonOne").attr("onclick","pressTwo()");
```

For example:

```
function pressOne() {
    $("#buttonOne").attr("onclick","pressTwo()");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
$("#buttonOne").attr("onclick","pressTwo()");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t02sh1xb/) - Inspect element to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this :

```
document.getElementById("buttonOne").setAttribute("onclick","pressTwo()");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dogvk0g3/)

---

But it would be better to add an other function which handle clicks :

```
<button id="buttonOne" onclick="onPress()">Press</button>
```

With the following javascript :

```
var pressOne = function() {
  ...
}

var pressTwo = function() {
  ...
}

function onPress() {
  if(..) {
    pressOne();
  } else {
    pressTwo();
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dogvk0g3/1/)